# Laravel 5.8 validation return to home after it fails while using Passport

Tags: json, laravel, api, validation, request

I have a store() method.

```php
public function create(StorePost $request)
{
    $post = Post::create([
        'title' => $request->title,
        'description' => $request->description,
    ]);

    return response()->json([
        'post' => $post
    ], 201);
}
```

In my StorePost class, I validated the request.

```php
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'title' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'description' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

When I tested it with Postman with wrong entries, for example, if I fill 'description' with a null value, it returns to the home page without any response or error. How can I retrieve the validation errors?

Answer (score 5):

I solved it just by adding 'Accept': 'application/json' in my request's header.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Laravel Form Request works both for API and non-API requests.

On requests made by a form, it will redirect back (to the original form url or home if not sent from a form) with an error bag on `$errors` variable available to the view.

On requests made by ajax (usually on APIs) usually have the header `Accept: application/json`, so Laravel automatically knows that you want the validation error bag as json on the response body instead of a redirect that makes no sense for an API.

Hope this can clarify thing to you.